# Code to calculate distance between two satellites using their TLE data?

Tags: artificial-satellite, coordinates

I am not acquainted with astronomy at all. I am developing an computer application which works on TLE data from space-track.org, and calculates things based on them. I need to find distance between two satellites from their TLE data. Now, I know there is an exact same question in this link:-  [How to calculate distance between two satellites using their TLE data?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27872/how-to-calculate-the-orbital-distance-between-2-satellites-given-the-tles)

But, being a person not aquainted with astronomy, I didn't get what was the answer there at all. If someone can point me towards directly code written by someone to do the same, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure how this isn't a duplicate.  Maybe you need to [edit] your question and make it clear you are looking for code.

Comment: If the answer there is unclear you have two options IMO: 1) Comment under it and ask for a more detailed explanation. **Be specific!** 2) Rewrite your question here, have it point to that question/answer and ask **specifically** what you do not understand about that answer.

Comment: For option 1) these are relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164035/how-does-lurker-gain-reputation-to-receive-privilege-for-commenting

Comment: **voting to reopen** The OP has edited the title "Code to calculate..." to match the existing explanation in the body of the question  "If someone can point me towards directly code written..." [as requested](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34793/code-to-calculate-distance-between-two-satellites-using-their-tle-data#comment108826_34793) and because that answer is just some analytical advice without any recommendations how to find code to calculate this. There may exist a better duplicate that advises SGP4, but the current dupe is the *wrong one* to point future readers to.

Comment: @firstlegagain1 [SGP4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_perturbations_models) is the thing you are looking for. It is the orbit propagator for which TLE's are written. Although they look like it, values in TLEs *are not real Keplerian orbital elements*. Choose your favorite computer language and search for "SGP4 propagator" + "your favorite language". You propagate each satellite separately to get positions, then subtract the two position vectors and take the length to get distance. It's old and tricky stuff; this is not a "roll your own" situation, find a popular, supported code.

Comment: Your SO profile mentions Python, so you can consider using [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) or you can just use the SGP4 implementation that Skyfield uses https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/python-sgp4

Comment: Also, it looks like the answer given in the claimed duplicate question assumes that an object moves with constant angular velocity around an elliptical orbit, which is incorrect.